# 'rename' with expression|replacement with a leading '-' (hyphen|minus)

Tags: rename, string, arguments, options

I have many files like `xyz_123_foo.ext` for which I would like to add `-bar` to the filenames at the end to result in `xyz_123_foo-bar.ext`. I tried:

```
rename . -bar. xyz_*
```

which resulted in:

```
rename: invalid option -- 'b'
```

followed by the usage text. I then tried variations with `'-bar'` and `"-bar"` to no avail.

How can I get `rename` to accept `-` as part of the replacement string?
Or would another command be more efficient or appropriate?

My shell is bash and I am using the `rename` from `util-linux` on SuSe Linux SLE12.

Comment: Which `rename` are you using? [There are many.][What's with all the renames: prename, rename, file-rename?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/229230)). Also, what OS are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mmv` is nice for tasks like this ex.

```
mmv -n -- '*.ext' '#1-bar.ext'
```

or for any dot extension

```
mmv -n -- '*.*' '#1-bar.#2'
```

Remove the `-n` once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: This seems really elegant, but I get an error and the usage when I use the `-n` Option:  
`> mmv -n '*.*' '#1-bar.#2'`  
`.../mmv: illegal option -- n`  
`.../mmv: [ -b ] [ -f Files ]  [ -s Source ] [ -t Target ]`    
Without `-n` nothing seems to happen

Comment: @astzge2 it seems our `mmv`s are different unfortunately - what is your OS?

Comment: I'm on SLE12. However, you've inadvertently answered my question! The `--` end-of-options in Linux was unknown to me until I saw your edit. Including that caused `rename` to stop interpreting `-bar.` as a `-b` option. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your `rename` is the Perl variant of the `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/$/-bak/' xyz_*
```

This uses a Perl expression that simply inserts `-bak` at the end of all given filenames through a substitution of `$` (the "end of line" anchor).

You could also use

```
rename '$_ .= "-bak"' xyz_*
```

which uses another Perl expression that appends the string `-bak` to `$_` (the "current thing" in Perl, here it's a filename).

For a shell loop solution:

```
for name in xyz_*; do
    mv -i "$name" "$name-bak"
done
```

Comment: The Perl rename won't help if they have the util-linux one...

Comment: @ilkkachu Added short note about that. That's also why I complemented the answer with a standard shell loop.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking about the PERL extension, `rename` (and not the `rename` from `util-linux`)...

```
rename 's/.ext/-bar.ext/' xyz_123_foo.ext
```

The result changes the file name to `xyz_123_foo-bar.ext`.

The portion within single quotes is a PERL regular expression. The `s` substitutes `.ext` in the file name with `-bar.ext`. One might combine this with `find`, assuming these files are in your home directory (`~`).

```
find ~ -type f -name '*.ext' -exec rename 's/.ext/-bar.ext/' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

When using the `util-linux` version of `rename` that is preinstalled on most Linux distributions, you can prepend `--` to the argument that contains the leading dash to escape it. That is the default `getopt` behavior.

```
rename '.' -- '-bar.' xyz_*
```